# subtotal of previous page in rdlc?

Tags: c#

i have a object data source bound to Rdlc.
i wanna subtotals of each page to be shown at the button of each pages' table,
and have summation of all previous pages (in fact : subtotal of previous page) on the top of each(not in header and not in footer)